# Directory existence check results NPE in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i am trying to verify that  given path is a directory or file in HDFS but it results NPE at fs.getFileStatus(path).isDir() line. i don't understand what's the issue here , even i verified the path  that's not null.

```
public static class RegexExcludePathFilter extends Configured implements
        PathFilter {
        private String path;
        String patterns = "hdfs://localhost:9100/user/input-new/ncdc/filterdata/2007.[0-1]?[0-2].[0-9][0-9].txt" ;
        Configuration conf; 
        Pattern pattern;
        FileSystem fs;

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path) {

        System.out.println(path);
        try {
            if(fs.getFileStatus(path).isDir()){
                System.out.println(path);
                return true;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return path.toString().matches(patterns);
    }

}
```

line 108 points to if statement in accept method.

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you inisialiezed FileSystem fs? I think that's the one that is null

make a constructor

```
public FileSystem(){
    fs = new FileSystem();

}
```

Edit: i just noticed you are using a static class so i dont know if making a constructor will work.

Comment: can you please describe little bit..?

Comment: Since line 108 points to the if statement i would guess either fs or path is null.

Comment: i checked it, path is not null and can not instantiate the filesystem constructor within the class.

Answer (score 0):

Well you've already established that path is not null. The only thing that can be null now, is the `FileStatus` object returned. Check if that is null.

When chaining methods together like this, you should always be sure that somewhere in the middle a method cannot return null. If that may happen, you should never chain. Basically the method that can return null, breaks the chain.